# Rails ActiveRecord: Is a combined :include and :conditions query possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, include, conditional-statements, findall

Imagine I have wiki Articles, with many Revisions.  I'd like to do a query with ActiveRecord through the database, which only returns those Articles which have Revisions which are updated in the past 24 hours.  Is such a thing possible?

I'd imagine it'd be something like:

```
Articles.find_all(:include => :revisions, 
                  :conditions => {:revision[updated_at] => 1.week.ago..Time.now.utc})
```

If this isn't possible, is there some type of raw SQL I could pass to find_by_SQL that'd do the trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need the article and don't need eager loading of all the revisions, you could use :joins instead. It uses less memory because it's not preloading all the revisions for each article. Use :include though if you will be doing something like `article.revisions`.

```
Article.find(:all, 
  :joins => :revisions, 
  :conditions => ["revisions.updated_at > ?", 24.hours.ago]
)
```

Comment: How about the case where you want to find ALL articles as well as JUST those revisions that were updated 24 hours ago? (instead of reducing the number of articles too).

Comment: If you want the articles and the revisions, I would use :include instead of :joins

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how exactly you have your models named, it's going to be something like this.

```
Article.find(:all, :include => :revisions, :conditions => ["revisions.updated_at > ?", 1.week.ago])
```