# how is this rails call getting an object from just an id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a User model and a UserMessage model (a model for holding the private messages between two users)

in my view i have..

```
<% if @message_items.any? %>
    <ol class="messages">
        <%= render partial: 'message_item', collection: @message_items%>
    </ol>
    <%= will_paginate @message_items %>
<% end %>
```

which i render with...

```
<li id="<%= message_item.id %>">
    <span class="user">
        <%= link_to message_item.user.name, message_item.user %>
    </span>
    <span>
        <%= message_item.title %>
    </span>
    <span>
        <%= message_item.body %>
    </span>
</li>
```

how is the object UserMessage(which is coming from message_item) able to render the User object? my design for the UserMessage just has the following attributes "id, user_id, from_id, title, body, created_at, updated_at".

i guess its from the user_id, and rails somehow makes the connection and is able to find the User object from the user_id. is that correct?

but i what i really want though, is the user from the from_id (the person sending the message). is there a way to retrieve that? i know doing something like.. message_item.user.from_id does not work.

the only way i could think of that works is by doing

```
<%= User.find(id= message_item.from_id).name %>
```

but that doesn't seem right putting so much code in my view. sorry but ive been super stuck. help would be much appreciated. thanks

Comment: Because a message has a user. Without knowing how the message class is defined, it's more difficult to tell you how to retrieve the "from" user; if it's a normal Rails association it might just be "message.from".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are looking for foreign_key option for belongs_to in model. So what you need is to specify something like sender/from relation with from_id in UserMessage message

```
belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: :from_id, class_name: "User"
```

Then in template you just call this relation in view.

```
message_item.sender
```

It should work same as `message_item.user`.

For further reference visit [documentation for associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to-label-Options)

In addition i recommend you not call `.name` method in template, but specify to_s method in your model. Good approach pointed by klump in his answer is to use `.include` method for better performance. It will load user data while loading `UserMessage` data, not in another query.

```
Article.find :all, :include => :revisions
```

Code was derived from another answer — [Rails ActiveRecord: Is a combined :include and :conditions query possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304766/rails-activerecord-is-a-combined-include-and-conditions-query-possible#answer-2304846)

Comment: Would it be possible to associate a UserMessage to 2 Users? I am thinking of something like this: 
`belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: :from_id, class_name: "User"`
`belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: :to_id, class_name: "User"`

This would combine quite much all the ideas here.

Comment: Yes you can. Almost exactly the way you wrote. Along with conventions you should put one of the users in the owner role, so the message "`belongs_to`" somebody.

Answer (score 3):

You need the following models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :received_user_messages, 
             :class_name => "UserMessage", :foreign_key => :receiver_id

  has_many :sent_user_messages, :class_name => "UserMessage", 
             :class_name => "UserMessage", :foreign_key => :sender_id
end

class UserMessage < ActiveRecord::Base

  # should have sender_id and receiver_id columns
  # make sure you index these columns

  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"   
  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => "User"

end
```

Do the following, to list the messages **received** by an an user:

```
current_user.received_messages(:include => :sender).each do |message|
  p "[#{message.sender.name}]: #{message.content}"
end
```

Do the following, to list the messages **sent** by an an user:

```
current_user.sent_messages(:include => :receiver).each do |message|
  p "[#{message.receiver.name}]: #{message.content}"
end
```

Comment: I agree with the assoc.. part

Comment: very interesting what you wrote now that im pondering it some more = ) much thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In your UserMessage class, make two class methods named `sender` and `recipient` that perform the complex queries you want. Then use these methods in your view.

Comment: I am pretty sure, this kind of method should be implemented through named scopes — http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope

Comment: Named scopes sounds more like the rails way.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set the associations. I guess that one user has many messages and one message belongs to one user.

add to the models:

*app/models/user.rb*

```
has_many :user_messages
```

*app/models/user_messages.rb*

```
belongs_to :user
```

You might need to add a column to your user_messages table, called `user_id`

When you fetch the messages in the controller, tell rails to load the associated user right away, so rails doesnt have to do this later on:

```
@message_items = UserMessage.includes( :user ).all
```

Now you can access the user object "owning" the message really easy:

```
<%= message_item.user.name %>
```

If you need all the messages owned by a user this also is easy now:

```
@user = User.find( some_id )
@user.messages # this returns an array with all the message objects
```